# Assigning outcome of another JSTL tag as value of one JSTL tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I've got this, which is working:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${sometest}">
        Hello, world!
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <fmt:message key="${page.title}" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And I want to change it to this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${sometest}">
        <c:set var="somevar" scope="page" value="Hello, world!"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="somevar" scope="page" value="<fmt:message key="${page.title}">"
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose
```

But of course the following line ain't correct:

```
<c:set var="somevar" scope="page" value="<fmt:message key="${page.title}">"
```

How can I assign to the *somevar* variable the string resulting from a  call to fmt:message?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`fmt:message`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/message.html) has a `var` attribute as well which does effectively what you want.

```
 <fmt:message key="${page.title}" var="somevar" />
```

That's all. Bookmark the [JSTL tlddoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/), it may come in handy.

Comment: thanks to you again... Interestingly there are three answers and three differents way to do it :)

Comment: You're welcome. The other two answers are technically the same and does indeed effectively the same. It's only more code and only proves that the presence and the use of the `var` attribtue in the majority of the JSTL `fmt` tags is relatively unknown ;)

Comment: Why is it called `fmt:message` if all it's doing is setting a variable. Is it formatting or modifying the variable in any way?

Comment: @Byron: Because it by default displays the message associated with the key when you omit the `var` attribute.

Comment: What is the scope of the variable we set this way?

Answer (score 9):

It is also possible to specify the value to set using the contents of the body, rather than through the value attribute:

```
<c:set var="somevar" scope="page">
  <fmt:message key="${page.title}"/>
</c:set>
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to do with:

```
<c:set var="title"><fmt:message key="${page.title}"></c:set>
<c:set var="somevar" scope="page" value="${title}" />
```

Since you can't use `<fmt:message .. />` on that spot is my experience, has to do with nesting like you suggested. Or go with @balusc suggestion ;-)

Comment: André van Toly: +1, thx to you too... I went with the shorter var attribute of the fmt tag that BalusC pointed out.